# Scanner delimiter passed with parameter?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I need to parse an input-line character by character, and this will be done through several methods. To do it char by char, I am using useDelimiter(""). My question is: do i need to set this delimiter in every method? Or is it enough once, at the beginning?

e.g.

```
void start() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    in.useDelimiter("");
    char first = in.next();
    readSecond(in);
    ...
}

void readSecond(Scanner in) {
    //in.useDelimiter(""); <-- is this needed?
    char second = in.next();
    ...
}
```

Example input: A5c*vd

Thanks !

Comment: Why not read in a line of input and process the entire line at once?

Comment: In your case, there's no need to use delimiter, at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't have to set it every time if you declare and initialize the Scanner object in the class body that the methods are in.  If you initialize the Scanner in each method, then I think you would have to set the delimiter in each method body.

Comment: I only initialize the Scanner in start(). From there on, I only pass it as parameter in the following methods. Does that mean using delimiter once in start() will be enough?

Comment: Oh, I see!  Thanks for the clarification.  I'm pretty sure using useDelimiter("") once is sufficient since the same Scanner object is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Once set, the delimiter stays the same.

Therefore, you do not need to set it again to the same value.